# Doctrine2 converts date type value to SQL format in wrong way

Tags: mysql, symfony, date, datetime, doctrine-orm

I have not yet understood where concretely is the problem is...
I have a Doctrine entity with date field:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="day", type="date")
 */
private $day;
```

Also I have an entity form with date type field:

```
$builder->add('day', DateType::class, ['widget' => 'single_text'])
```

And when I try to save the form with value "2016-02-14" I see that it becomes "2016-02-13" (a day earlier) in MySQL and in PHP after saving. When I began looking for logs, I saw that the query parameter value is "2016-02-13 23:00:00".

But I don't understand why it happens this way.
I have the same time and timezone in system (Ubuntu), PHP and MySQL (Europe/Moscow timezone).

I use date type, not datetime, so there should not be time at all.

When I tried to debug it, I saw that code

```
    #vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateType.php

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value !== null)
            ? $value->format($platform->getDateFormatString()) : null;
    }
```

works correctly. It makes correct format "Y-m-d", but in the symfony log value is with time.

I need an advice about how to find, where my date transforms.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and used a quick-and-dirty hack. On the setter used for the $day property, just set the time to be midday.

```
public function setDay(\DateTime $day)
{
    $this->day = $day;
    $this->day->setTime(12, 0, 0);

    return $this;
}
```